# How much buzz is there in 式 of 手打ち式 udon noodles?

Tags: food, copywriting

A lady in front of me in a line to the register had a pack of udon noodles in her basket. It read:

> うどん・手打ち式

How much buzz is there in such a phrase? Is it comparable to using 手打ち風? Or could it have some merit to it?

Also, I assume that a real hand-made udon makers would simply write 手打ちうどん. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: 「手打ち風」だと、「手打ちっぽい」(つまりホントは手打ちじゃない)ってことになるよね・・・(もしかしたら「手打ち式」も、実は「手打ちうどん」じゃなかったりして・・・？)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, we are talking legal hype here.

「[手打]{てう}ち[式]{しき}うどん」 (= "handmade-***style*** udon")  is just the best-sounding and most-appealing name to the consumers that you can legally give to machine-made udon.

If the udon were actually handmade, it would definitely be named 「手打ちうどん」 without using 「式」 as you stated so that its naturally higher price would effortlessly be justified.

「～～式」 is a terribly vague "suffix" describing what style/form/origin a product or service represents.  Most consumers would be aware of the inaccuracy of the description in their heads, but it gives us a certain level of comfort and appeal that is enough to make us feel that it might actually be close to the real thing.

「～～[風]{ふう}」 is one step even more vague and unreliable.  It would only appeal to those who know close to nothing about the real thing.  I often order the 「ミラノ風ドリア」 at Saizeriya because I like how it tastes, but not because it tastes like doria made and served in Milan.  I have never even been to Italy!  From that name, however, I just "know" that the dish must be pretty much a Japanese (or Saizeriya's) creation.

Comment: “-風,” “-esque.”