# How is 風 used in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I was watching karakau jouzu anime and I found this sentence. I know how everything works except 風. A girl was looking at an ice cream fridge and said

> 焼き芋風アイス 売り切れだ

Comment: Hint: how are you pronouncing 風?

Comment: 「焼き芋風**の**アイス**が**売り切れだ」. [Related](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/what-is-the-meaning-of-%E9%A2%A8%E3%81%B5%E3%81%86-here).

Comment: ^ 「焼き芋風アイス」 is fine as it is. It doesn't *necessarily* have to be 焼き芋風**の**アイス. eg  「[いちご大福風アイス](https://www.conveniice.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/igodfk01-768x576.jpg)」「[焼き芋ようかん風アイス](https://www.conveniice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ykim-yknf01.jpg)」「[ティラミス風プリン](https://www.meito.co.jp/assets_c/2019/06/2019tiramisu-pudding-thumb-400xauto-546.jpg)」「[ミラノ風ドリア](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28708/9831)」

Answer (score 2):

-風（ふう）

-style

韓国風焼肉  Korean BBQ

和風パスタ　Japanese style pasta

yakiimo (baked sweet potato) ice cream  - [it exists!](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%84%BC%E3%81%8D%E8%8A%8B%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS737US737&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUnYGu_8DwAhXUqZ4KHeB-BQoQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1895&bih=1036)